# Find a substring within a textfile in Python

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, find, substring

So I am trying to extract a link within a textfile in Python -- this link varies from textfile to textfile but has the same format. I tried using the re library but keep getting errors.

The syntax of the link is:

```
docs.com/searchres.aspx?docformat=all&docid=[SOME NUMBER] -
```

So the end of the link has a specifying number in the SOME NUMBER field and at the end of the link there is a ' - ' 
How can I search, find, and save this link from a textfile. 
Thank you -- this is my first time posting on SO

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Is there only one such string in the text file? If so, this should be trivial to just read the file and determine if the string `"docs.com/searchres.aspx?docformat=all&docid=["` exists, and then extract the next characters until you hit a `"]"`.

Comment: Yes only one such string exists

Comment: You can also use Regular Expressions. It should be very easy to match that pattern. They are not very difficult, but David's suggestion would be easier if you're a beginner. But believe me you'll need to learn regular expressions if you plan to continue as a programmer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a Python solution that uses memory maps. A few caveats:

1. You said there was only one instance in the file, and if there is more than one, it will return the first.
2. I put this together quickly from some old code. If `]` is not in the text file, it will continue reading. Take a look at the `mmap` documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/mmap.html) to see how you might modify the code to be more robust.

EDIT: Python's code formatter hates me, so I had to make some minor changes to get it to block properly. Sorry about that.

```
match = open(db, 'r')
try:
    search = mmap.mmap(match.fileno(), 0, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ)
    index = search.find(str(target))
    if index != -1:
        #"This entry exists. We have the index of it, now read the line."
        search.seek(index)
        #"Seek to the index."
        strOut = ""
        read = search.read(1)
        while read != ']':
            strOut = strOut + read
            read = search.read(1)
        search.close()
        match.close()

        print strOut
    else:
        #-1 indicates it's not in the file
        print strOut
except Exception as err:
    match.close()
    print strOut
```

Answer (score 0):

So this response is simple, but works for small files. When you say "save this link" I assume having the url in a string variable is good enough.

```
import re

f = open(filename_str, 'r')
file_content = f.read()
p = re.compile('docs.com(.)*\-')
m = p.search(file_content)
if m != None:
    link = m.group(0)
```